# Do I need a transit visa to pass through El Alto International Airport (LPB), La Paz, Bolivia?

Tags: transit-visas, bolivia, indonesian-citizens, lpb

I am an Indonesian citizen flying from Peru to Chile, with a transfer through El Alto International Airport (LPB), Bolivia.

I have looked, but I can't seem to find a straight answer as to whether or not I would need a transit visa for Bolivia, or even if such a thing exists.

Answer (score 2):

While visas are usually required to enter Bolivia, there is a [TWOV (Transit without visa option)](http://visados.com/en/visa-for-Bolivia):

> 1. TWOV is permissible for travellers continuing their trip to a third country within 24 hours on condition that they:
>
>    - Have tickets with confirmed reservations.
>    - Have all documents needed for their next trip.
>    - Do not leave the airport.
> 2. There is no hotel accommodation available at the airport.
> 3. Citizens of People's Republic of China must have a transit visa.

Note that last requirement in particular is only for Chinese, and won't affect you.

Re there being no hotels at the airport, this is confirmed on [sleepinginairports](http://www.sleepinginairports.net/casa/lapaz.htm), where if you don't want to sleep in the airport - your only other option is in La Paz City, which is a 30ish min drive away.